# How do I add add 2 arrow each, one top arrow button and one bottom arrow button to my react table crud connected to my sql?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

[image][image][image]

```
<div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      {/*}
                      <th>S/N</th>
              */}
                      <th>S/N</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th onClick={displaySort}>Contacted? </th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
```

This is my current table code,

how do I add 1 pointing up arrow button and 1 pointing down arrow button, each is a different element or arrow so that I can each add an onClick method?

```
.cont {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 8rem;
  border: solid 2px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2.5px 2.5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 8rem;
  top: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.up:hover {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 8rem;
  bottom: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down:hover {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 2.5px 2.5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
```

above is my css if you need it.

So my header is Contacted but how can I add one top arrow button beside it and one down arrow button beside it so that I can add an onClick method for each?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an icon and then `transform: rotate` it using a class. Then set you elements items using ***positioning***.

Embed the icons in the parent element and then set the parent to `position: relative` then on the arrows, set their `position:absolute` and then set their ***left*** and ***top*** *positions* *relative* to the parent element.

For the JS, use a loop on the arrow class and then check **`classList`** for ***up*** or ***down***, use the **`event.target`** to get the element being clicked.

I use a ***dataset*** on the ***parentNode*** to show that the `event.target` is working.

```js
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow')

function upDown(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('up')) {
    console.log('up', e.target.parentNode.dataset.id)
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains('down')) {
    console.log('down', e.target.parentNode.dataset.id)
  }
}

arrows.forEach(arrow => {
  arrow.addEventListener('click', upDown)
})
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}

table {
 width: 100vw;
}

th {
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

th:nth-of-type(2){
  width: 9rem;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2.5px 2.5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 9rem;
  top: .2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.up:hover {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 9rem;
  bottom: .2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down:hover {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 2.5px 2.5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Contact 1 info: John Doe</th>
    <th class="cont" data-id="John Doe">Contacted 1
      <i class="arrow up"></i>
      <i class="arrow down"></i>
    </th>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: hello thank you! however my contacted is a <th> element not a <div> element

Comment: @fyceheist Updated as table elements

Comment: doesn't work though.... @dale landry you can refer to my questio nto see what my contacted looks like

Comment: mine is th element not td i edited question to include css

Comment: The positioning of elements using `relative` /`absolute` will work with `th` elements as well, you will likely have to play with top/left positions and padding, etc to get it to work properly on your project.